# Is it possible to query for users in Firestore?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I see that there's a row for each user in the "Authentication" section of Firestore with their data. Am I able to query for users in this table and add columns, or to create a new collection of users with a one-to-one mapping from user in the authentication section to user in the collection? If it's the latter, is there any way to both create a new user account and create the corresponding document in the collection as part of a single transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have an "Authentication" section.  Firestore only lets you read and write data into its database.  Firebase Authentication is a different product that keeps track of logged in users in a way that's completely separate from Firestore.  You can't query users in Firebase Authentication using Firestore.  In fact, you also can't even query Authentication using the mobile client libraries (because that would be a possible security hole for your app).

If you want to query for all users in your app, you're going to have to do perhaps arrange for each user to write a document in some collection in Firestore that can be queried by Firestore client libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud Functions with Admin SDK. Make a http endpoint or a http Callable that queries at [admin.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=pt-br#list_all_users). But this is not a secure. The best way to do that is registering a firestore docuement whenever user is created using [functions.auth.user().onCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_auth_.userbuilder.html#on-create)